# Swift 4: Timer Crashing - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, timer, unrecognized-selector

I'm trying to call an instance of Timer and print "A second has passed" for each second that elapses. I'm following The Complete iOs 11 & Swift Developer Course on Udemy. The instructor does exactly this and his code works, yet mine is crashing.

Here's the code:

```
var timer: Timer! = Timer()

@IBAction func cameraPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    timer.invalidate()
}

func processTimer() {
    print("A second has passed")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: Selector("processTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

It should start the timer upon running the application and then stop it when I press the cameraPressed button. However, it's erroring out with:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance...

and

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I'm new to Swift and the other StackOverflow problems that seem similar to this aren't solving my problem. I've tried changed the "Timer!" optional to "Timer?" and changing "Selector("processTimer")" to "#selector(processTimer)" and I'm still not getting it to work.

Comment: You need `#selector`. Update your question with your attempt to use that.

Comment: And `func processTimer()` may need to be `@objc func processTimer()` for later versions of Swift

Comment: I would strongly recommend using [`Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:repeats:block:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/2091889-scheduledtimer) over [`Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer). In most cases, Swift's closures are preferable to selectors. They're type safe, easier to program with, more performant, and more consistent with the rest of Swift's APIs

Answer (score 1):

The callback function `processTimer` is not correctly declared:

```
@objc func processTimer() {
   //your code here
}
```

You need to add the **@objc** keyword before the function in order to be called in the `Timer` callback.
Also, in general I think is better to use `#selector` keyword instead.